# Is traditional plant material improvement sufficiently descriptive to be considered full disclosure

Tags: patentability, claims

Patent [WO2008110876 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2008110876A1?cl=en) discloses a method to enhance the oil production capability of tobacco seeds by means of either mutagenising (chemically inducing mutations) or hybridising existing varieties of tobacco.

Can this, essentially random, process be considered sufficiently full disclosure to permit reproduction and thereby fall under the protection of a patent?

As a second item, if the initial claim is bypassed, can any subsequent claim that refers to the initial claim be safely considered to be inapplicable?